# Undefined procedure in prolog query with C#

Tags: c#, prolog

When I do this in swi-prolog, it works.
but when I use C# query, there is an error saying "undefined procedure".

I donnot know what to do.

```
lives_in(Habitat,Animal):-animal_habitat(Animal,Habitat).
query = new PlQuery("lives_in("+value+",Animal)");
foreach (PlQueryVariables q in query.SolutionVariables)
{
 lbConsult.Items.Add(q["Animal"].ToString());
}
```

ERROR likes: SbsSW.SwiPlCs.Exceptions.PlException
in detail：$exception    {"'$c_call_prolog'/0: Undefined procedure: lives_in/2"} SbsSW.SwiPlCs.Exceptions.PlException

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: The ERROR occur when execute this line:foreach (PlQueryVariables q in query.SolutionVariables)